# Why Dom4JDriver is appending a newline at the beginning of the xml content?

Tags: java, xstream, dom4j

I am using the XStream library (1.4.10) and the Dom4jDriver to generate xml content from a Java object. The problem is that it appends a new line at the beginning of the content. Anyway to turn this off?

```
    Dom4JDriver dom4JDriver = new Dom4JDriver();
    dom4JDriver.getOutputFormat().setSuppressDeclaration(true);

    XStream xStream = new XStream(dom4JDriver);
    xStream.processAnnotations(MyClass.class);
    String myContent = xStream.toXML(myClassInstance); //extra '\n' appended at the start of the string
```

MyClass.class:

```
@XStreamAlias("myClass")
public class MyClass{

  private String something;

  private String somethingElse;
...........
```

Generated xml:

```
\n<myClass>\n <something>blabla</something>\n......
```

I know that I can just use myContent.subString(...) to get rid of the first character, but it doesnt seem so clean to me. I am also doing this for a lot of operations so I would rather not have that line to begin with for performance's sake. Any advise? Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried **DomDriver** in place of **Dom4JDriver**?

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I would have wished to keep the Dom4JDriver because of the performance advantage but the job was done in the end :)